# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object Zend AccessCheck

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-acl

I'm learning Zend from [Alexander Romanenko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsdDvfMznH0) video , I have problem about `zend_acl`, I've declared database connection in `application.ini`:

```
resources.db.params.dbname     = zftutorial
resources.db.params.username   = root
resources.db.params.password   =
resources.db.params.hostname   = localhost
```

I've added **LibraryAcl.php** in my models :

```
<?php
class Model_LibraryAcl extends Zend_Acl
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this -> add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('book'));
        $this ->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('add'),'book');
        $this ->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('edit'),'book');

        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('books'));
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('list'),'books');

        $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'));
        $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'),'user');

        $this ->allow('user','books','list');
        $this->allow('admin','book','edit');
        $this->allow('admin','book','add');
    }
}
```

and changed **Bootstrap.php** :

```
protected function _initAutoload() 
{
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array( 'namespace' => '', 
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH)); 
    $acl = new Model_LibraryAcl;
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $fc->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($acl, $auth));

    return $moduleLoader;
}
```

I've also added **AccessCheck.php** in plugins :

```
<?php
class Plugin_AccessCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    private $_acl = null;
    private $_auth = null;
    public function __construct(Zend_Acl $acl, Zend_Auth $auth){
        $this ->_acl = $acl;
        $this->_auth = $auth; 

    }
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $resource = $request->getControllerName();
        $action = $request->getActionName();

        $identify = $this->_auth->getStorage()->read();
        $role = $identify->role;
        if (!$this->_acl->isAllowed($role , $resource, $action)){
            $request->setControllerName('authentication')
                    ->setActionName('login');
        }
    }
}
```

and last of all , this is my **database-zftutorial** in localhost:

```
 Database: `zftutorial`<br>
 Table structure for table `books`<br>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `title`, `author`) VALUES
(1, 'onvane ketab', 'author ketab avali'),
(2, 'onvane ketab dovomi', 'author ketab dovomi'),
(3, 'onvan3', 'author varc3'),
(4, 'onvan4', 'author varc4');<Br>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;<br>
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `role`) VALUES
(1, 'john', 'pass1', 'user'),
(2, 'george', 'pass2', 'admin');
```

This error occurred :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\Zend\workspaces\test\application\plugins\AccessCheck.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because there has not yet been an authentication.
Try this:

```
if ($this->_auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $identify = $this->_auth->getStorage()->read();
    $role = $identify->role;
}
```